# Syncfusion Xamarin.Forms formatted text in generated PDF

Tags: android, pdf, xamarin.forms, pdf-generation, syncfusion

I want to ask you if it's possible to create formatted text like

> This text is normal and this one is **bold**. We also have an *italic* font slope.

in this way:

```
graphics.DrawString("This text is normal and this one is bold. We also have an italic font slope.", font, PdfBrushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
```

I tried to use order the documentation a HTML Styled Text (https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-text#adding-a-html-styled-text) but PdfHTMLTextElement Class is not supported in Xamarin.
A next choice was to insert RTF text (https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-text#inserting-rich-text-format-contents) it's also impossible to use that in Xamarin.

I'd also to have a formatted string inside a cells of PdfLightTable. Have you any tips how to achieve this?

I'd appreciate your help very much.

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/TEditor) for you.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your reply! I don't think this HTML editor can be used for creating PDF files, especially in Syncfusion Xamarin PDF Control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present the ***PdfHTMLTextElement*** is not supported in Xamarin platform. In order to achieve your requirement, we have created the workaround sample for applying style to the text based on HTML tags.

Please find the 
[Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/GettingStarted-1489761307)

Thanks.

Comment: Hey man, you really saved my life!!! It works like a charm! However I can't imagine that nobody solve this problem in the past. It was unable to find any appropriate solution in order to do it in a best practice... I'm sure this workaround will be useful for most developers. Thanks.